# Can not access pointer from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

```
struct SomeStruct{
    int someValue;
};

vector<SomeStruct *> vec;

int getSomeValue(){             // Gets called from another thread
    return vec[0]->someValue;
}

int main(){
    SomeStruct *structure = &SomeStruct();
    structure->someValue = 42;

    vec.push_back(structure);
}
```

I've got a code like this. The problem is, when I'm calling `return vec[0]->someValue` in `getSomeValue()` which gets called from another thread, VS says: "Access violation" and opens the `memcpy.asm` file.

So I'm thinking to myself, that I cannot access pointers which were created in a different thread, which sound a bit awkward to me.

Where is the problem?

Comment: `SomeStruct *structure;` declares an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: As it currently stands, it's not valid code. Are you missing a `new` before `SomeStruct()`?

Comment: Instead of posting fake code, please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). There's no point in any of us guessing about it.

Comment: Your pointer will be valid in other threads - your problem is elsewhere. Perhaps the first thread is done with the object (was it on the stack) or it deletes it while the thread is still using it. It's hard to tell with your kinda-psuedo-code!!

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is ill-formed, i.e. it is erroneous, formally non-compilable. Expression `SomeStruct()` produces a temporary object.  It is illegal to apply built-in unary `&` operator to a temporary object in C++.

If your compiler somehow allows applying `&` to a temporary, it most likely destroys that temporary immediately afterwards, meaning that your pointer is left pointing nowhere (a dangling pointer). No wonder the code crashes when you attempt to dereference an invalid pointer.

Threads have nothing to do with it though.

Answer (score 2):

This here is <strike>a recipe for *undefined behaviour* (UB)</strike> some illegal code which should not compile on a standards compliant implementation. You cannot take the address of a temporary:

```
SomeStruct *structure = &SomeStruct();
```

GCC produces the following output:

> error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

If your compiler accepts this, it may leave you with a dangling pointer. De-referencing that would be undefined behaviour.

Note that none of this is related to multi-threading.

Comment: @AndreyT You are absolutely right. I edited this (and +1 to you).

Answer (score 1):

You should say thanks to VS creators for C++ "features", that they added to the language. One of them - implicit conversion of temporary to lvalue. In legit C++ you would not be able to take address of temporary and following line:

```
SomeStruct *structure = &SomeStruct();
```

would not compile and it should not compile. You are taking address of a temporary variable which is destroyed right after this line.